# How to create given html format and convert it in pdf in asp.net using itextsharp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

Can you please tell me how to create html format and convert to pdf in asp.net using itextsharp?

[Here is Image of invoice format of pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iavpC.png):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [itext documentation](https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/pdfhtml-configuration-options)

You can use:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf("<p>input</p>", new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
```

or :

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File("input.html"), new File("output.pdf"));
```

Example with `ConverterProperties`:

```
public void createPdf(String baseUri, String src, String dest) throws IOException { 
    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
    List<IElement> elements =
        HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(src), properties);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    for (IElement element : elements) {
        document.add(new Paragraph(element.getClass().getName()));
        document.add((IBlockElement)element);
    }
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Its not working please give me another solution